# Is it possible to print files using PHP

Tags: php, windows, printing

I know you can write files using PHP, but I was wondering if it was possible to print these files directly to a printer, on a Windows machine. Are there any pre-built functions to do this?

EDIT: I'm on localhost by the way

Comment: Output the php file code using another php file that read your source file . on the client side a javascript can run and print

Comment: If your app will always be on a localhost then printing should work out of the box. Additionally you can implement special CSS for printer and a JavaScript print button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about whether it is possible to print from the server to a machine the server happens to connect to, then the answer is, [Yes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php). (With CUPS it is possible to get [this](http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/) working with Linux/Mac).

If you're trying to get something to print on a user's printer, you will need to use [JavaScript](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm)

Comment: Actually on the client side printing can be done without JavaScript too :) JavaScript usually is used just for the print button implementation which is not necessarily needed.

Comment: Yeah actually Javascript (Jquery better yet :D) did what I was looking for. Thanks all for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2):

If the printer is attached to the machine the php process is running on (or available via the network and setup in windows), you can use PHP's [COM functions](http://php.net/com) to print.

Comment: I remember seeing stuff a few years ago regarding CUPS and PHP printing, but I think that's primarily Apple/UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the future with newer technologies like [Google Cloud Print](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/overview.html). For now you will have to print client sided unless the printer is connected to your server directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is - but only under windows: http://php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php

Comment: "These functions are only available under Windows 9.x, ME, NT4 and 2000." Good one ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is my worked solution

1. install an old version of xampp that contain php_printer.dll file for my case i install xampp-win32-1.6.8-installer.exe
2. enable the extintion from php.ini in php foldar and apache foldar
3. restart your apache server
4. run this code

   ```
   $printer_name = "80mm Series Printer"; 
   $handle = printer_open($printer_name);
   printer_start_doc($handle, "test_print.php");
   printer_start_page($handle);
   $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 100, 100, 400, false, false, false, 0);
   printer_select_font($handle, $font);
   printer_draw_text($handle, 'This sentence should be printed.', 100, 400);
   printer_delete_font($font);
   printer_end_page($handle);
   printer_end_doc($handle);
   printer_close($handle);

   ?>
   ```