# use printer via php

Tags: php, windows, printing, localhost, intranet

I have four computers and one printer in Intranet and I installed WAMP on one of Windows machines. Now I want to execute PHP script, from window machine browser (or via Ajax etc) to print data. I need to know will it be possible? if yes then how?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299206/is-it-possible-to-print-files-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [printer](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php) functions:

```
<?php 
    $printer = "\\\\hostname\\printername"); 
    if($ph = printer_open($printer)) { 
       $fh = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
       printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); 
       printer_write($ph, $content); 
       printer_close($ph); 
    } else {
        echo "Can't connect to printer"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai,  
sorry i didn't mention that i tried printer_open function and it supports only if php_printer.dll library reside inside xampp/php/ext and i tried all php_printer.dll files to make compatible with php 5.3.x version. but could not succeeded. i want to know if there is any other solution apart from this.

Comment: Why don't use an older version of `WAMP` that has that `.dll` ?

Comment: Which version of WAMP should i use to work with php_printer.dll?

Comment: get a `php_printer.dll` see for what PHP version it is, and download the WAMP that uses that `PHP` version

Comment: Look [here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) for versions, I believe there is also a `5.3` version

Comment: Thanks Mihai, hats up for you and i got three more solution including your answer with the duplicate link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299206/is-it-possible-to-print-files-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299206/is-it-possible-to-print-files-using-php)